# How to hide comments in Wordpress Blog page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress based website and I am new for wordpress. I have tried to hide comments on blog page.

I changed "Go to Settings » Discussion » untick Allow people to post comments on new articles" in admin panel.But not able to remove comments on blog page.I just need to display blogs on page not comment.

Would you please give me proper suggestion about how to hide/remove comments on blog page?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

I got solution

I just commented on below line in my code and it is working.

`if ( ! $is_page_builder_used && comments_open() && 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_pagescomments', 'false' ) ) comments_template( '', true );`

Comment: you can refer this link : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/turn-off-comments-on-static-home-page

Comment: there is one another way is by CSS that mentioned in above URL

Comment: @AlbertAkki I already tried this but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Visit your WordPress theme directory there is a file called post.php

from this file comment this code

```
  // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }
```

if there is not post.php then you need to first find the file where from it is appear in your blog page .

Answer (score 1):

- **To Remove comments on blog page** -

  Open up your theme's **page.php** and find the following line:

  You can comment/remove this line of code if you want to disable comment on blog page.

  **`<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>`**

  **`<?php comments_template(); ?>`**

.

- **To Disallow comments from already Publish posts**-

  1) Go To **`Dashboard > All Post`**.

  2) Select them all.

  3) "**Edit**" under bulk actions.

  4) Then hit **apply > choose "`do not allow`"** next to comments and hit update posts.

  5) Then Update.

[image]